# Replacing a conditional statement with a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a guessing game that generates a random number which the user guesses. This guessing game must use some kind of loop. Right now it is enclosed in a function that is called when the user clicks a button, and a boolean that limits the number of guesses the user can make.

To my understanding, a loop runs without stopping until its conditions have been satisfied. If I were to have a loop in this situation, the final output would be the loop's last iteration. NumGuesses would have a value of 6 because that was when the loop stopped. How can I replace the conditional with a loop and still have it work?

```
//Declare variables and constants 
var guessesLeft;                               //number of guesses the user has left
var userGuess;                                //user's guess
var highLimit = 1000;                         //high parameter
var numGuesses = 1;                           //number of guesess the user has guessed
var allowedGuesses = 6;                      //number of allowed guesses
var NL = "\n";                               //new line

    //function to be called when the user presses Submit Guess
    function guessingGame() { 
        //random number that is generated
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * highLimit + 1); 
        if (numGuesses <= allowedGuesses) { 
        userGuess = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and " + highLimit + ": " , "")
        userGuess = parseInt(userGuess);
        guessesLeft = (allowedGuesses - numGuesses) + " guesses left.";
            //If userGuess is in the specified parameters
            //If userGuess is larger than 1 and smaller than the higher parameter
            if ((userGuess > 1) && (userGuess < highLimit)) {

                //If userGuess does not equal randNum
                if (userGuess !== randNum) {

                    //If userGuess is too low
                    if (userGuess < randNum) {
                        //output 
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "You guessed too low! Please guess again. " + NL + "Your current number of guesses: " + numGuesses + NL + "You have " + guessesLeft;
                    }
                    //If userGuess is too high
                    else if (userGuess > randNum) {
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "You guessed too high! Please guess again. " + NL + "Your current number of guesses: " + numGuesses + NL + "You have " + guessesLeft;
                    }//end if                      
                }
                else {
                    //If userGuess is correct
                    document.numForm.gameResults.value = "You guessed correctly!";
                }//end if
            }

            else {
                document.numForm.gameResults.value =  "Your guess was out of the specified parameters. Please try again. " + NL + "Your current number of guesses: " + numGuesses + NL + "You currently have " + guessesLeft;
                    //user may have entered their guess wrong
                    numGuesses--;
            }//end if 
            //add to number of guesses so the program stops when it reaches the allowed number
            numGuesses++;
        }//end outer if statement
        return false;
    }//end guessingGame()
```

Comment: Hi, could you give more details how you want the game to work, i.e. how do you play the game. you code is neat enough and your explain it well.. but i'm struggling to understand the goal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem statement expects you to block waiting for user input as opposed to triggering a function in response to a DOM event.

Have a look at [`window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Placing this in a loop would block the loop until the user responded.

Answer (score 0):

Using `prompt()` as suggested by [retrohacker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240521/6738706) and a `do {} while ()` loop, the following code demonstrates this in action:

```js
var minNumber   = 1;    
var maxNumber   = 2;
var guessesLeft = 3;

var numberToBeGuessed = minNumber + 
  (Math.random() * (maxNumber - minNumber + 1) | 0);
var succeeded;
var message = 'Make a guess';

do {
  if (prompt(message) == numberToBeGuessed) {
    alert('Correct, the number is ' + numberToBeGuessed);
    succeeded = true;
  } else {
    guessesLeft--;
    message = 'Try again, ' + 
      guessesLeft + 
      ' guess' + (guessesLeft > 1 ? 'es' : '') + 
      ' left';
  }
} while (!succeeded && guessesLeft)
```